# PHP get the 5 characters after the 'strstr' match

Tags: php, match

The variable `$page` includes a webpage (full HTML file), but I want to filter that file on this line:

`<a href="http://[website]/[folder]/`

And I want that the 5 characters after parsed in a string.

But that strings is multiple times inside `$page`, so the numbers has to be stored in an array too.

So if a match is found with `<a href="http://[website]/[folder]/23455`, how do I get the '23455' into `$nums[0]`

And if another match is found with `<a href="http://[website]/[folder]/12345`, the '12345' will be put into `$nums[1]`

Comment: Use a [**DOM parser**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php).

Comment: Maybe use a Regular Expression...

Comment: may be with the call back function that add all the requested items into a array.  see http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/ maybe this regular expression works for you:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you are just trying to get the ending piece of the url and then do a comparison then store the value in an array? I believe this code should do the trick.

```
$nums = new array(); //declare your array
$a = new SimpleXMLElement('<a href=<a href="http://[website]/[folder]/23455">Your Link</a>'); //create a new simple xml element
$a = $a['href'];
$array = explode("/",$a); //split the string into an array by using the / as the delimiter

if($array[count($array)-1] == '23455') { //get the count of the array and -1 from the count to get the last index then compare to required number
$nums[0] = '23455'; //store value in array
} else if ($array[count($array)-1] == '12345'{
$nums[1] = '12345'; //
}
```